# How do I write this SQL query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

I have two tables.

1. users
2. payroll_management

Now I want to query which `id` is not in `payroll_management` table.

This is my SQL query.

```
select id from users where id not in (SELECT user_id FROM payroll_management)
```

How do I write this query in Laravel?

Comment: Do you have relationships set up? `User::doesntHave('payrollManagement')->get()` would be a easy one-liner. Please show what you have tried, and include more information. Stackoverflow is not a free-coding service; you're expected to make an attempt to solve your own issue first.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')
    ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('payroll_management')->pluck('user_id'))
    ->get(['users.id']);
```

That would be a first way using Query Builder.

If you wish to use Models, you should show us how you created them and how (and if) you specified the relationships.

If you did set the relationships, you should have a relation with PayrollManagement and this way you could do `Users::doesntHave('PayrollManagement')->get(['id']);`